# Induced electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

Let's consider a thin cylinder of radius $r$ with a charge in is outer surface. It is made of an isolator. Let the magnetic field be parallel to its axis. If the magnetic field changed by $dB$ in time $dt$, electromotive force $\varepsilon = -\frac {dB \pi r^2}{dt}$ would be induced.

Why will there be an induced electric field on the outer surface of the cylinder of intensity $$E = \frac {\varepsilon}{2\pi r}$$ What will be its direction?

Can this be justified without very advanced math, i.e. with integrals of one variable at most?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very classical question in college physics, sometimes it can occur in high school physics level. If you use Faraday's law of induction, you should get the answer easily. Faraday's law is given as:
$$
\oint_{\partial \Sigma} \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{l} = -\frac{d}{dt}\int\int_{\Sigma} \vec{B} \cdot d\vec{S}
$$
First of all, choose the a circular contour $\Sigma$ whose center locates at the center of cylinder. And you should notice that the electric field $\vec{E}$ at the circular contour is tangential with the circle and at every point of the circle $\vec{E}$ has the same magnitude due to the symmetry. In this way, the left part of the integral will reduce to:
$$
\oint_{\partial \Sigma} \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{l} = 2\pi RE
$$
where $2\pi R$ is circumference of the circular contour. And the right part of the integral is just your electromotive force. And $E = \frac{\epsilon}{2\pi R}$is your answer.

Btw, you should find some examples in your textbook about how to use Faraday's law. And normally it will be one of the example.

Comment: Well, first of all, we always use the Faraday's law in the form $$\varepsilon = - \frac {d\Phi}{dt}$$
It's easy that $$\frac{d\Phi}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}\left(\int_S \vec{B} d\vec{S} \right)$$ But why is it $$\varepsilon = \oint_{\partial \Sigma} \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{l} $$ (why are the sides equal)? Is $\oint_{\partial \Sigma}$ the intergral over the countour?

Comment: it is just part of the law. Please see [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction).

Comment: And why is the electric field tangent?

Comment: right hand rule.

Comment: Aaa... because the electric field will try to "undo" the flux change. thanks!